# Live $200 NLHE hand review, pocket deuces in MP

Tags: hand

Live $1/$2 NLHE full ring

Hero is in MP with 2♣2♥, 40-50 BB stack

---

Preflop

UTG limps, UTG+1 raise to $7, Hero calls, 4 folds, SB calls, 2 folds

---

Flop Q♠2⋄5⋄(3 players, pot: $25)

SB checks, UTG+1 bets $10, Hero raises to $20, SB calls, UTG+1 calls

---

Turn 9♠ (3 players, pot: $85)

SB bets $25, UTG+1 calls, Hero raises to $56 all in, SB shoves* and UTG+1 calls

*SB's stack size was barely larger than mine

---

River T♠

UTG+1 shows

> AsKs
>  
>  what, if anything, was i supposed to do differently here?  i mean seriously?? <6% at the flop and this guy is calling reraises, what a game

Comment: It sounds as if you want advice on how to have made UTG+1 fold?  That shouldn't be the case...but what aspect about your play are you questioning?

Comment: basically, is this a spot where you have to just suck it up and deal with losing to a guy who was basically pissing away chips?  im somewhat new to the live game and try to protect my bankroll unless i have the best of it

Comment: Your flop raise was too small.

Comment: oh *UTG+1* had the spades... I would have put the SB on spades.

Answer (score 2):

I would not of played the deuces in the first place. From early and middle position I would not even limp with deuces in a fast game, much less called a raise.

The problem with deuces is that you need to flop a set to continue with them after the flop and any hand you make with them including flopping sets and full houses is a perilous hand.

If you limp with deuces in a one-two game, it cost you about $15 on average to flop a set. Flopping a set is the only scenario with deuces were the hand becomes dominate. Every other scenario with deuces, if you can check down the hand, have a negative return on your limp. Hero paid seven dollars to see the flop here meaning his investment to buy a set was a little over fifty dollars.

When you factor in the overhead of loses with three deuces weighed against the potential win, it becomes very difficult to add it all up for a positive EV. Most of us are not good enough to play deuces, especially for a raise.

Great players can find places to play them, their most common play being to send them to the muck, other players especially inexperienced players should not even waste the money to limp with them.

My opinion on pocket three is a little higher, at least with threes I might make a large pot flopping set over set against some schmuck playing deuces.

Answer (score 0):

Your min raise to $20 on the flop gave UTG+1 7.5:1 to call.  With two overs, runner runner flush draw, and 2 runner runner straight draws.  That is an easy call.   SB was getting 2:75:1.

Call would be a better play. You did not get much more in the pot and now you risk shutting down betting if a blank hits.

UTG+1 is getting odds to call the turn if he thought an A or K was good. And real close to odds even if the A or K was not good.

If you had jammed the flop you might have gotten folds but then you only pick up $35 on a hand that wants to get it in.

If you just checked the flop and jammed the turn then UTG+1 would only be getting 2.2:1 and should have folded.

You got coolered but that min raise on the flop was of no value.